# Shell script to search for a pattern in a file using if else

Tags: scripts, tcsh

This is my script, I want to find a pattern in a file. I know the exit status of `grep -q '<Pattern>' '<file>' && echo $?` is 0 if pattern is found. But I am getting **if: Expression Syntax** error.

```
 if ( (grep -q '<Pattern>' '<file>' && echo $?)==0  ) then
 echo "Pattern found"
 else
 echo "Pattern not found"
 endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest not using `csh` (or its variants) for new scripts, for the reasons discussed here [Why shouldn't I program in csh?](http://www.cs.uleth.ca/~holzmann/C/shells/csh_avoidit.html)

However the correct syntax appears to be:

```
if ( { grep -q 'Pattern' file } ) then
  echo "Pattern found"
else
  echo "Pattern not found"
endif
```

i.e. the inner brackets need to be braces, `{ ... }`. You don't need to echo `$?` in order to test the exit status.

Alternatively, you can use the `$status` variable:

```
grep -q 'Pattern' file
if ( $status == 0 ) then
  echo "Pattern found"
else
  echo "Pattern not found"
endif
```

In `tcsh`, the variable `$status` may be replaced by `$?` - but not all `csh` implementations appear to support this.

Comment: I am getting an error in the first script. The second one works fine. Thanks.

Comment: @sid what is the error in the first case?

Comment: error: Missing }

Comment: @sid did you remember to leave space between the filename and the closing `}`? otherwise it will be treated as a character of the name

Answer (score -1):

i think you have not closed condition with "fi".

try below it should be work.

if ( (grep -q '' '' && echo $?)==0  ) then
 echo "Pattern found"
 else
 echo "Pattern not found"
 fi

Comment: No. `csh` syntax is different than `sh`/`bash`. See http://beefchunk.com/documentation/tips/unix_tips_and_tricks/node40.html